# Is a docker image available for DocDokuPLM?

Tags: docker

Does anyone know of a demo site, docker image, or some other way to quickly try out DocDokuPLM?

Also, does anyone know if the project is alive?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one.
https://github.com/docdoku/docdoku-plm-docker

I deployed a system with this docker-compose.

There is a persistence problem that requires some changes to the db-volume configuration.

```
  db:
    image: postgres:13.1-alpine
    env_file: ./env/db.env
    volumes:
      - db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    networks:
      - network
```